# multiple expected identifier or '(' before ':' token when compiling android_npapi.h file

Tags: android, android-ndk, npapi, browser-plugin

As stated above the android_npapi.h provides multiple errors of the above type at this point:

```
struct ANPInterface {
    uint32_t    inSize;     // size (in bytes) of this struct
};

enum ANPLogTypes {
    kError_ANPLogType   = 0,    // error
    kWarning_ANPLogType = 1,    // warning
    kDebug_ANPLogType   = 2     // debug only (informational)
};
typedef int32_t ANPLogType;

struct ANPLogInterfaceV0 : ANPInterface {
    /** dumps printf messages to the log file
        e.g. interface->log(instance, kWarning_ANPLogType, "value is %d", value);
     */
    void (*log)(ANPLogType, const char format[], ...);
};

struct ANPBitmapInterfaceV0 : ANPInterface {
    /** Returns true if the specified bitmap format is supported, and if packing
        is non-null, sets it to the packing info for that format.
     */
    bool (*getPixelPacking)(ANPBitmapFormat, ANPPixelPacking* packing);
};
```

Starting from the "struct ANPLogInterfaceV0 : ANPInterface" every struct definition containing an inheritance of ANPInterface gives the above error.

For more info on said header file : [android_npapi.h](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/external-webkit/Source/WebKit/android/plugins/android_npapi.h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to compile the code including it as C, or C++? That header uses struct inheritance, which means it needs to be compiled as C++.

Comment: Right, that sounds more likely here.

Comment: @smorgan yes, that was the problem.. i figured it out later. Thanks for your input!